# Need a comparable Function in C# to display a Variable as Array like in VB.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

If a function in VB.NET wants an Array as param, like this:

```
 private function DoSomeStuff(int[] numbers)
```

I can write in VB.NET this, and give the int in {} as array

```
dim example as Integer = 10
doSomeStuff({example})
```

Is there something comparable in C#?

Comment: `private void DoSomeStuff(params int[] numbers)`? So you can put `DoSomeStuff(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: `DoSomeStuff(new[] { value1, value2 })`

Comment: i cant change the function. I just have some objects and want take the Objects in a Method that accepts only Arrays as parameter. I dont wanna convert my Objects to Arrays so i thought there is a simple spelling like in VB.NET to display a variable as a array.

Comment: DoSomeStuff(new[] { value1, value2 })  <--- thats it, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below

```
int example = 10;

doSomeStuff(new int[] { example });
```

Comment: Not that brevity is always better, but could simplify to: DoSomeStuff(new[] {example});